# What does mean "done" in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning

Is the "done" meaning "acceptable"?

> In reading **done** outside class, select a short passage of no more than
>   100 words. In the passage, locate pronouns/referring words and their
>   noun referents.

In addition, Grammarly website tool (grammarly.com) reports an error to "outside" and says: replace it with "outside of"

Reference: "Delta's Key to the Next Generation TOEFL Test" book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "done" could be replaced by

> In reading *that you have done* outside (of) class...

It is a participle phrase, that describes the reading. It is equivalent to the relative clause starting "that".

Participle phrases like this are common:

> A shoe *made in China* was found on the beach.
>   An apple *eaten by a worm* is disgusting.
>   He gave me a sock *worn by his brother*.

Comment: And must we state "outside of"?

Comment: I consider "of" to be optional. Outside can function as a preposition, so "of" is not required. It can also be a noun, with "of".  Both are correct

Comment: Why "that you have done" rather than "that you will do" or "that you are intended to do"?  The participial phrase doesn't have a tense, and *done in the future* seems a more likely and more useful meaning.

Comment: @James K don't you think @_Gary Botnovcan is right? Text piece offers to do something out of class.

Answer (score 1):

Done in this sentence means:

> All reading outside of class

And Grammarly is right, it should be *outside of class*